# ERROR :177: timed out after mMajorChangePending=0

Tags: swift

I use piemonte/Player to show video in my app but I found an error in the console:

> 2015-11-15 17:58:30.238 summonerMenu[5361:200890] 17:58:30.238 ERROR:    177: timed out after 0.012s (180 180); mMajorChangePending=0
>   2015-11-15 17:58:43.652 summonerMenu[5361:200891] 17:58:43.651 ERROR:    177: timed out after 0.012s (1331 1332); mMajorChangePending=0
>   2015-11-15 17:58:48.789 summonerMenu[5361:200891] 17:58:48.789 ERROR:    177: timed out after 0.012s (1773 1774); mMajorChangePending=0

My Xcode is 7.1 iOS 9

This is my code:

```
let videoUrl = NSURL(string: "http://cdn.leagueoflegends.com/champion-abilities/videos/mp4/0067_05.mp4")!

class PlayerViewController: UIViewController, PlayerDelegate {
    private var player: Player!

    // MARK: object lifecycle

    convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    // MARK: view lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.autoresizingMask = ([UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight])

        self.player = Player()
        self.player.delegate = self
        self.player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 300)

        self.addChildViewController(self.player)
        self.view.addSubview(self.player.view)
        self.player.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.player.setUrl(videoUrl)

        self.player.playbackLoops = true

        let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGestureRecognizer:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.player.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.player.playFromBeginning()
    }

    // MARK: UIGestureRecognizer

    func handleTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        switch (self.player.playbackState.rawValue) {
        case PlaybackState.Stopped.rawValue:
            self.player.playFromBeginning()
        case PlaybackState.Paused.rawValue:
            self.player.playFromCurrentTime()
        case PlaybackState.Playing.rawValue:
            self.player.pause()
        case PlaybackState.Failed.rawValue:
            self.player.pause()
        default:
            self.player.pause()
        }
    }

    // MARK: PlayerDelegate

    func playerReady(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerPlaybackStateDidChange(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerBufferingStateDidChange(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerPlaybackWillStartFromBeginning(player: Player) {
    }

    func playerPlaybackDidEnd(player: Player) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: there's no debugging for it ,, :/ , i search and i found that it's maybe from Xcode ,,